# Using Dynamic Layouts in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to use layouts in vuejs, however i hit a road block at the point where components have to be imported dynamically. Webpack throws an error.

```
<template>
  <component :is="layout">
    <slot />
  </component>
</template>

<script>
const defaultLayout = './AppDefaultLayout';
export default {
  name: "AppLayout",
  computed: {
    layout() {
      const layout = this.$route.meta.layout || defaultLayout;
      return () => import('@/layouts/${layout}.vue');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/layouts/${layout}.vue'
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration resolve as module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to use the syntax for [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but that requires backticks (not quotes, which would create a regular string):

```js
import('@/layouts/${layout}.vue'); ❌ single quotes does not create a template literal

import(`@/layouts/${layout}.vue`); ✅
```

Comment: thanks for the help @tony19, i had actually used backticks and still got the error, another issue was declaring paths with the @ alias, a simple './' and a relative path works just fine.